# Hybris 1811 SmartEdit Loader is keep on loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I am new to Hybris smartedit. I logged into https://localhost:9002/smartedit/#!/. I wanted to edit a home page but as soon as I clicked on Home page the loader is keep on loading and getting below error in browser console.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: smarteditcommons is not defined at
Object.<anonymous> (VM27143 cmssmartedit.js:1)

https://localhost:9002/smartedit/static-resources/dist/smartedit/js/postsmartedit.js
net::ERR_ABORTED 404

WARNING: 

Tried to load AngularJS more than once.
```

Below is the warning I am getting in hybris log:

```
INFO  [hybrisHTTP25] [SmartEditUtil] cmsTicketId found in request, It
is smartEdit flow. INFO  [hybrisHTTP30] [SmartEditUtil] cmsTicketId
found in request, It is smartEdit flow. WARN  [hybrisHTTP30]
[SocialLoginBeforeViewHandler] Facebook API not set for CMSSite zales
WARN  [hybrisHTTP30] [SocialLoginBeforeViewHandler] Google API not set
for CMSSite zales
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: What is your frontend? Spartacus, or custom AngularJS?

Comment: I think custom Angular js

Comment: Did you follow the guide for SmartEdit setup? https://help.sap.com/viewer/86dd1373053a4c2da8f9885cc9fbe55d/1905/en-US/6d55d5fba206425b9acecda9f2311483.html

Comment: Yes, followed everything properly.

Comment: I am getting the same error exactly reported here: https://answers.sap.com/questions/12771625/endless-loadingreloading-of-smartedit-after-adding.html